Alerting with pod restart count
I was configuring alerts in google cloud console using promql query. I wanted to get pod restart alerts. For that I had used following promql query:
sum by(pod_name)(
kubernetes_io:contianer_restart_count(monitored_resources="k8s_container")
-
kubernetes_io:contianer_restart_count(monitored_resources="k8s_container") offset 10m
) > 0

The problem is it keep alerting for the same pod restart like continuously every time there is a restart.
What I wanted was at least there should be a 10mins gap between the alerts so that we don't get bombarded with the alerts. But we are getting bombarded right now.
Other details:
alert trigger value: Any time series violates
retest window: 0secs
evaluation interval: 1min
incident autoclose duration: 30mins
Please help.
Thanks!!!

From the alerting policies with a PromQL-based condition you can change your alerting configuration like below

Retest window(10m)- which prevents the condition from being met due to a single measurement or forecast. You can set it to 10 minutes.

Evaluation interval- The evaluation interval in an alerting policy is the time between evaluations of a query in seconds. You can set it to 5 minutes or 10 minutes.

Incident auto close duration: Keep as it is 30 mins.


Or else try to use rate function which gives you a restart count window like below
sum by(pod_name)(
rate(kubernetes_io:container_restart_count{monitored_resources="k8s_container"}[10]) ) > 0

which  helps  you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

Yaa, well
retest window we want cause we need to detect pod restarts, even if it one in number.
And
evaluation interval we can't increase since it will prevent the alert from capturing another pod restart.
But the query is what I wanna try, lets see what it gives as output.

Adjusting the parameter is the best choice, As you said it is not possible then try a Rate function which may help to resolve the issue.
